# how to use ffmpeg with librtmp to stream cv::mat

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, rtmp

I am using  ffmpeg to stream some cv::mat to rtmp server ,I know avio_open2() function call some functions in librtmp like RTMP_init()、RTMP_SetupURL().But I can't control the details of rtmp when just only using ffmpeg to stream cv::mat(I want to resume rtmp connection when network recovered after network broken).Could someone tell me if there is existing tools or codes to convert cv::mat to RTMP_packet and stream them by using librtmp.Thanks

update(relevant code)：

```
//encode and write Frame to rtmp server
static int encode_and_write_frame(AVCodecContext *codec_ctx, AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx, AVFrame *frame)
{
    AVPacket pkt = {0};
    av_init_packet(&pkt);
    int ret = avcodec_send_frame(codec_ctx, frame);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error sending frame to codec context!\n");
        return ret;
    }
    ret = avcodec_receive_packet(codec_ctx, &pkt);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving packet from codec context!\n" );
        return ret;
    }
    int ret1 = av_interleaved_write_frame(fmt_ctx, &pkt);
    av_packet_unref(&pkt);
    return ret1;
}

//scale cv::mat and copy it's value to avframe,then encode_and_write_frame  
void Streamer::stream_frame(const cv::Mat &image, int64_t frame_duration)
{
    if(can_stream()) {
        const int stride[] = {static_cast<int>(image.step[0])};
        sws_scale(scaler.ctx, &image.data, stride, 0, image.rows, picture.frame->data, picture.frame->linesize);
        picture.frame->pts += frame_duration; //time of frame in milliseconds
        int ret = encode_and_write_frame(out_codec_ctx, format_ctx, picture.frame);
        std::cout<<"stream_ret"<<ret<<std::endl;
    }
}

// Initialization
int Streamer::init(const StreamerConfig &streamer_config)
{
    init_ok = false;
    cleanup();

    config = streamer_config;

    if(!network_init_ok) {
        return 1;
    }

    //initialize format context for output with flv and no filename
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&format_ctx, nullptr, "flv", nullptr);
    if(!format_ctx) {
        return 2;
    }


    //AVIOContext for accessing the resource indicated by url
    if (!(format_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
         //init and handshake with rtmp server.
        int avopen_ret  = avio_open2(&format_ctx->pb, config.server.c_str(),
                                     AVIO_FLAG_WRITE, nullptr, nullptr);
        if (avopen_ret < 0)  {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to open stream output context, stream will not work\n");
            return 3;
        }
        rtmp_server_conn = true;
    }

    //use selected codec
    AVCodecID codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
    out_codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);
    if (!(out_codec)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find encoder for '%s'\n",
                avcodec_get_name(codec_id));
        return 4;
    }

    out_stream = avformat_new_stream(format_ctx, out_codec);
    if (!out_stream) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate stream\n");
        return 5;
    }

    out_codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(out_codec);

    if(set_options_and_open_encoder(format_ctx, out_stream, out_codec_ctx, out_codec, config.profile,
                                    config.dst_width, config.dst_height, config.fps, config.bitrate, codec_id)) {
        return 6;
    }

    out_stream->codecpar->extradata_size = out_codec_ctx->extradata_size;
    out_stream->codecpar->extradata = static_cast<uint8_t*>(av_mallocz(out_codec_ctx->extradata_size));
    memcpy(out_stream->codecpar->extradata, out_codec_ctx->extradata, out_codec_ctx->extradata_size);

    av_dump_format(format_ctx, 0, config.server.c_str(), 1);

    picture.init(out_codec_ctx->pix_fmt, config.dst_width, config.dst_height);
    scaler.init(out_codec_ctx, config.src_width, config.src_height,config.dst_width, config.dst_height, SWS_BILINEAR);

    if (avformat_write_header(format_ctx, nullptr) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not write header!\n");
        return 7;
    }

    printf("stream time base = %d / %d \n", out_stream->time_base.num, out_stream->time_base.den);

    inv_stream_timebase = (double)out_stream->time_base.den/(double)out_stream->time_base.num;

    init_ok = true;
    return 0;
}

}
```

Comment: Cv::mat is a raw pixel buffer. You must first encode it using ffmpeg/libavcodec/x264

Comment: @szatmary yes,I am using ffmpeg to encode Cv::mat and stream them to rtmp server,But I don't want to use the ffmpeg‘s internal rtmp because I can't control the rtmp handshake like  RTMP_Connection  under different network conditions. So I want to use ffmpeg to encode and librtmp to stream.can ffmpeg convert cv::Mat to RTMP_packet.Could someone tell me，thanks

Comment: Please provide some code. I have no idea where in the process you are. Do you have encoded AVPacets yet?

Comment: @szatmary sorry for my late，I have posted the relevant code above，Could you tell me how to convert cv::mat to RTMP_packet or the better way to  re-handshake with rtmp-server with ffmpeg livestream interface when rtmp  connection lost,thanks again